# Regex search and edit text simultaneously with multiple cursors

Tags: regular-expressions, search, multiple-cursors

I'd like to search for a pattern with regex and simultaneously cut or edit all instances of that pattern.

Is there a ready-made function for this?

Atom, for example, has [one such package](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-search-and-copy-results-from-atom/28244/2) - by pressing Alt+Enter, all search results would be selected for simultaneous editing.

Comment: How about using the `multiple-cursors` package by Magnar Sveen https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el and watching the Emacs Rocks video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNa3axo40qM demonstrating some of its many usages?

Comment: `M-x iedit-mode` is another one, available from MELPA.